# Redirect after comment submission to post

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect my comment form submission to the post details page where all comments should be displayed. How do I pass in the unique id for post that the comment is related to into my URL for redirecting to that post?

post_detail.html

```
...
  <p><a href="{% url 'comment_new' comment.post.pk %}">Create New Comment</a> 
...
```

urls.py

```
...
    path('comment_new/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name = 'comment_new'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
...
```

views.py

```
...
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
...
```

model.py

```
...
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, 
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name = 'comments'
    )
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 280)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args = [str(self.post.id)])
...
```

#### UPDATE 2

Following the instructions of NKSM, I am able to create a url that is linked to the post the comment is referring to but I receive this error upon submission.

No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.

views.py

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `post_pk` argument to your path:

```
path('comment_new/<int:post_pk>/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_new'),
```

Then use [**get_success_url**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) to redirect to the post:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=(self.kwargs.get("post_pk"),))
```

The default implementation for `form_valid()` simply redirects to the `get_success_url(`).

You can also add your post to comment in the method `form_valid`:

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs.get("post_pk")
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

---

**UPDATE**

your **urls.py**

```
...
path('comment_new/<int:post_pk>/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name = 'comment_new'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
...
```

your **views.py**

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'comment_new.html'
    form_class = CreateCommentForm
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs.get('post_pk')
        return super().form_valid(form)
 
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=(self.kwargs.get("post_pk"),))
```

Comment: def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('post_detail', args=(self.kwargs.get("post_k"),)) -> i assume post_k is a typo and should be post_pk

Comment: Also I did as shown above and recieve the error "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model." I even tried using get_absolute_url. Not sure why it isn't being called

Comment: @IrfanSuzali, this must be work, where did you added get_success_url? This error means that you are calling originally get_success_url where success_url is required!

Comment: @IrfanSuzali, share a link with screenshot of your CommentCreateView.

Comment: I added an update to my post with the code

Comment: @IrfanSuzali, i updated my answer, you have to add `get_success_url`.